# Вывести список установленных rpm-пакетов, содержащих в названии заданное слово

Tags: linux, консоль, rhel

Как вывести список установленных rpm-пакетов, содержащих в названии заданное слово?

Comment: содержащих слово где? если в названии, то как обычно: `$ rpm -qa | grep слово`

Comment: В названии пакета. Поправил вопрос. Ваш ответ помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно искать именно по названию, то `grep` не совсем то, что нужно.
Стандартный поиск будет смотреть только на название пакета, без версии:

```sh
rpm -qa \*слово*
```

Для примера, сравнение количества найденых пакетов:

```sh
rpm -qa \*2* | wc -l
#59
```

```sh
rpm -qa | grep 2 | wc -l
#549
```

В первом случае у нас вернулись только пакеты, содержащие в названии 2, например `python2-pip` или `dotnet-hostfxr-2`
Во втором случае соответствие искалось по всей строке, например `git-cvs-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.noarch` где 2 есть только в версии и т.д.

---

В чем заключается различие:
`rpm -qa` по умолчанию возвращает несколько полей `имя`-`версия`.`архитектура`
программа `grep` ищет совпадение по всему stdout переданному через `pipe`, поиск же совпадения при установке маске программы происходит только по полю `имя`.
Что бы списки установленных программ были идентичны при использовании маски или программы `grep` можно выводить только названия программы:

```
rpm -qa --qf %{NAME}\\n | grep слово
```

Comment: а почему $ rpm -qa *слово*  и  $ rpm -qa | grep *слово*  выводят разные результаты? В чем принципиальная разница этих команд?

Comment: @KirillKirik, покажите пример

Comment: Первая звёздочка должна быть заэкранирована. Подробности в `man $SHELL`.